# can't check variable for spaces using find or findstr

Tags: batch-file

this checks `%file%` for a `space` and if not found changes dots into spaces.

`echo "%file%" | find " " || set "file=%file:.= %"`

the problem is that when a filename has no spaces it still behaves as if it does. same with `findstr /c:" "`. can I force `space` support here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space between `"%file%" and the pipe. This space is being included in the string`echo`ed so space is *always* detected.